# About Pointers and Value of operator

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

```
....
int a[3][3]={0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8}
printf("%d",a+1);  // output 1
printf("%d",*(a+1));  //output 2
....
```

why output 1 and output 2 are same addresses? If it would have 1D array then applying 'value of' operator will give corresponding values in the array but here getting address, Confused!

Comment: It is not 1-dimensional array. Maybe in memory it is represented as 1d

Comment: It is Undefined Behavior to print pointers using `%d`. Both `a+1` and `*(a+1)` are pointers and you should use `%p` after casting them to `void*` if you wish to print them. That being said, both `a+1` and `*(a+1)` will have the same _value_ but different _types_.

Comment: Why wouldn't they be? Both pointers point to the same spot in memory. Why does it surprise you? Just stop trying to print pointer values with `%d`. `%d` cannot be used with pointers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both `a+1` and `*(a+1)` evaluate to same address but their type is different.

`a+1` is of type `int (*)[3]` and `*(a+1)` is of type `int *`.

Also, `%d` is not the correct format specifier for printing a pointer. Instead, you should use `%p`

```
printf("a+1 = %p\n", (void*)(a+1));  // output 1
printf("*(a+1) = %p\n", (void*)(*(a+1)));  //output 2
```

---

**EDIT**
[OP asked in comment - *`My question is whey they evaluate to same adress`*
To illustrate this by giving example, editing my answer]

To understand this in a simple way, lets consider an example of 1D array:

```
int b[3] = {3,4,5};

    b[0] b[1] b[2]
    +-----------+
 b  | 3 | 4 | 5 |
    +-----------+
    ^
    |
  base address of array (which is also the address of first element)
```

Lets print the `&b` and `b`:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int b[3] = {3,4,5};
    printf("&b = %p\n", (void*)&b);
    printf("b  = %p\n", (void*)b);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
&b = 0x7ffee9f5fa2c
b  = 0x7ffee9f5fa2c
```

both `&b` and `b` referring to same address. **The address of array and address of first element of array is numerically same but their type is *different*.**

`b` is **pointer to first element of array**<sup>1)</sup> whereas `&b` is **pointer to an array of three `int`**.

The type of `b` is `int *` whereas the type of `&b` is `int (*)[3]`.

We can see the difference by doing a simple pointer arithmetic -  add `1` to these pointers.
When you add `1` to these pointers, the result will be different because there **type is different**.
`b+1` will result in `address of first element of array b + 4 bytes` *[assuming the size of integer is `4` bytes]*
`&b+1` will result in `base address of b + (3*4) bytes`

```
    +-----------+
    | 3 | 4 | 5 |
    +-----------+
    ^   ^
    b   |
        |
       b+1

    +-----------+
    | 3 | 4 | 5 |
    +-----------+
    ^           ^
   &b           |
                |
              &b+1
```

Lets print the value of `&b+1` and `b+1`

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int b[3] = {3,4,5};
    printf("&b = %p\n", (void*)&b);
    printf("&b+1 = %p\n", (void*)(&b+1));
    printf("b  = %p\n", (void*)b);
    printf("b+1  = %p\n", (void*)(b+1));
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
&b = 0x7ffeee6e7a2c   
&b+1 = 0x7ffeee6e7a38
b  = 0x7ffeee6e7a2c
b+1  = 0x7ffeee6e7a30
```

Back to your scenario of 2D array:

`a` is array of `3` one dimensional array.
The in memory view of the 2D array would be like this

```
    +-----------+
 a+0| 0 | 1 | 2 |  <--- first 1D array
    +-----------+
 a+1| 3 | 4 | 5 |  <--- second 1D array
    +-----------+
 a+2| 6 | 7 | 8 |  <--- third 1D array
    +-----------+
```

`a+1` is base address of second 1D array *[equivalent to `&b` in above example]*

`&a[1] --> &(*(a+1)) --> a+1`<sup>1)</sup>

and `*(a+1)` is address of first element of second 1D array *[equivalent to `b` in above example]*

`&a[1][0] --> &(*(*(a+1)+0)) --> &(*(*(a+1))) ---> *(a+1)`<sup>1)</sup>

`a+1` is of type `int (*)[3]` and `*(a+1)` is of type `int *`.

Lets add `1` to these pointer

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int a[3][3]={0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8};
    printf("a+1 = %p\n", (void*)(a+1));  
    printf("(a+1)+1 = %p\n", (void*)((a+1)+1)); 
    printf("*(a+1) = %p\n", (void*)(*(a+1))); 
    printf("(*(a+1)+1) = %p\n", (void*)((*(a+1))+1));
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
a+1 = 0x7ffee167ea1c
(a+1)+1 = 0x7ffee167ea28
*(a+1) = 0x7ffee167ea1c
(*(a+1)+1) = 0x7ffee167ea20
```

Hope this clarify all of your doubt.

---

1)
From C Standards#6.5.2.1

> The definition of the subscript operator [] is that E1[E2] is identical to (*((E1)+(E2))).

In context of the above example of 1D array `b`:
`b[x]` is identical to `*(b+x)`.

To access the first element of array `b`, you will write `b[0]` and to get the address of first element of array `b`, you will do `&b[0]`.

`&b[0] --> &(*(b+0)) --> &(*b) --> b`

That means `b` will give address of first element of array `b`.

The operator `&` is used to get the address and the operator `*` is used for dereferencing. These operators cancel the effect of each other when used one after another. Hence, `&(*(b+i))` is equivalent to `b+i`.

Comment: Both answers provide useful pieces to the puzzle. Nicely done.

Comment: My question is whey they evaluate to same adress

Comment: The difference in type may be illustrated by comparing the effect of `(a+1)+1` and `(*(a+1))+1`.  The former will point to `a[2][0]`, while the latter will point to `a[1][1]`.

Comment: @ArijitKarali I have edit my answer and given example to explain they are different but why they evaluate to same address.

Answer (score 2):

`a+1` is the address of an array.
(The array is `a[1]`– the address can also be written `&a[1]`.)

`*(a+1)` is the array at that address (that is, the array `a[1]`).

When you pass an array as an argument, the value is implicitly converted into the address of that array's first element.
In your case, `*(a+1)` (i.e. `a[1]`) is converted into `&a[1][0]`.

The address of an array is the same as the address of that array's first element – `&a[1]` denotes the same location as `&a[1][0]`, but with a different type.

Answer (score 0):

In memory, there is no 2D array because memory is 1D. So all 2D arrays are stored as a sequence of 1D arrays.

Secondly, wherever you write only the name of an array, it means the address of the first element of that array.

Now in your code `a+1` and `*(a+1)` evaluates to the same address, u can see this by replacing `a` with the address of `a[0][0]`.