# what is the difference between *pt in int (*pt)[2] and pt in int *pt?

Tags: c

For example

```
    int (*pt)[4];
    int target[3][4] = {{1,3,4,6},{2,4,5,8},{3,4,6,7}};
    pt = target;
    *pt = target[0];
```

why it is "[Error] invalid array assignment"

Comment: Which line is getting the error?

Comment: @barmar   The last one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OP has asked two question.

***Question 1***

> what is the difference between `*pt` in `int (*pt)[2]` and `pt` in `int *pt`?

In this

```
int (*pt)[4];
```

the `pt` is a pointer which can point to an array of `4` integers.

Assume array of `4` integer - `int arr[4] = {1,3,4,6};`

You can do

```
pt = &arr;  //pt is now pointing to array arr.
```

In context of your program

```
pt = target;
```

this is equivalent to

```
pt = &target[0];
```

because `target` is address of first element of array which is a `1D` array:

```
target  ->  target + 0  ->  &(*(target + 0)  ->  &target[0]
```

and `target[0]` is array of `4` integers.

Note that *type* of `*pt` is `int [4]` and when you use `*pt` in your program you will get address of first element of array it is pointing to and which is also the base address of array:

```
*pt  ->  *pt + 0  ->  &(*(*pt + 0))  ->  &(*pt)[0]
```

Consider this

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void)
{
    int (*pt)[4];
    int target[3][4] = {{1,3,4,6},{2,4,5,8},{3,4,6,7}};
    pt = target;  // pointer pt pointing to target[0] array
    printf ("%p\n", (void *)*pt);
    printf ("%p\n", (void *)&target[0][0]);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
# ./a.out
0x7ffee35389e0
0x7ffee35389e0
```

Coming to 2<sup>nd</sup> part of question, in this statement

```
int *pt;
```

Here, `pt` is pointer to an integer.

Assume you have array of `4` integer - `int arr[4] = {1,3,4,6};`

When you do

```
pt = arr;
```

is equivalent to

```
pt = *arr[0];
```

because

```
arr  ->  arr + 0  ->  &(*(arr + 0))  ->  &arr[0]
```

So, `*pt` will give the value at the address it is pointing to.

Consider this example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void)
{
    int *pt;
    int arr[4] = {1,3,4,6};
    pt = arr;
    printf ("%p\n", (void *)pt);
    printf ("%p\n", (void *)arr);
    printf ("%p\n", (void *)&arr[0]);
    printf ("%d\n", *pt);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
# ./a.out
0x7ffee86f0a00
0x7ffee86f0a00
0x7ffee86f0a00
1
```

***Question 2***

> why it is "[Error] invalid array assignment"
>
> ```
> *pt = target[0];
> ```

Note that the `pt` is pointer to array of `4` integer. The type of `*pt` - `int [4]`. An array name is not a *modifiable* lvalue and you cannot assign to it. Hence, compiler is giving error on this statement.

Comment: Is it only in 1D array that "target" can be the address of first element of array？what if in 2D? for example, "target[0]", Is it a array rather than a address of the first array's element?

Comment: `target`, `&target`, `target[0]`, `&target[0]` and `&target[0][0]` are evaluate to same address. That means when you print them they all will give same address. The difference lies in their **type**. [**This will clarify your doubt**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51605849/about-pointers-and-value-of-operator/51607231#51607231), check it thoroughly.

Answer (score 3):

`int (*pt)[4]` declares `pt` as a pointer to an array.

C doesn't allow assigning arrays; e.g. you can't do:

```
int a[4] = {1, 2, 3, 4};
int b[4];
b = a;
```

If you want to copy an array, you need to use a loop, or you can use `memcpy`:

```
memcpy(pt, target[0], sizeof target[0]);
```

Answer (score 2):

Adding slightly to the excellent answer given by Barmar,

```
int (*pt)[4];
```

declares a *pointer to array of int [4]*

```
int target[3][4] = {{1,3,4,6},{2,4,5,8},{3,4,6,7}};
```

declares an *array of arrays int [4]* (3 of them in a common 2D array)

```
pt = target;
```

on access `target` is converted to a pointer to its first element. (array / pointer conversion) Since its first element is an *array of int [4]* it is converted to a *pointer to array of int [4]* which is *type-compatible* with `pt`. See [C11 Standard - 6.3.2.1 Other Operands - Lvalues, arrays, and function designators(p3)](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3.2.1p3)

```
*pt = target[0];
```

Since `pt` is a *pointer to array of int [4]*, when you dereference the pointer you are left with an *array of int [4]* -- and arrays are not lvalues and not assignable. [Id at (p1)](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3.2.1p1).